# Program to print gCal or iCal calendars in a monthly one calendar per column format

Tags: macos, mac, calendar, google-calendar, calendar.app

I'm moving my family off of using the low tech "Boynton Mom's Family Calendar" to schedule things but I'd like to be able to create a monthly printout of the calendar in the same "Boynton" format (I'm sure it has an official name). The format is kind-of like a spreadsheet where each row of the calendar is a different day of the month and there is a separate column for each person in the family. I have all our calendars on Google but they are also accessible from iCal on the Mac. Is there a Mac program that can get the data from gCal or iCal print out the calendars in the Boynton format?

Comment: This is what you are referring to: http://www.familieswithpurpose.com/images/familyplanitopen1resized.jpg?

Comment: Yes, that's the calendar.

Comment: The first column is for "Mom" entries and the other four columns are for the rest of the family.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Grab app under Utilities...you can capture the whole screen, window, or a selection and print it out

Comment: Both iCal and gCal will let you print out the calendars they display on the screen but they don't have a mode or view where they display it on the screen in the Boynton format.